# Develop bargraphs from json object list directly

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have multiple json scripts with a similar format as:

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "slug": "xyz",
    "supplier": "xyz.limited",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "mass",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "",
            "value": "0.24",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "kg",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "length",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "assumed to be length",
            "value": "58.0",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "mm",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "height",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "assumed to be height",
            "value": "25.0",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "mm",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "width",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "assumed to be width",
            "value": "58.0",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "mm",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "momentum-storage",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "",
            "value": "0.050",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "N m s",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "maximum-torque",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "",
            "value": "0.007",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "N m",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "voltage",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "voltage is given in DC current",
            "value": "12.0",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "V",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "maximum-power",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "",
            "value": "9.0",
            "minimumValue": "",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "W",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "lifetime",
            "productConfiguration": "base",
            "description": "",
            "value": "",
            "minimumValue": "5.0",
            "maximumValue": "",
            "measurementUnit": "yr",
            "uuid": "",
            "attributeClassUuid": "",
            "productUuid": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Each of these files have different set of attributes defined. I would like to plot the number of times each attribute is repeated across all files. I try to do this using python3.5 functionalities 'os' and 'panda.DataFrame'. However, got lost somewhere! Can use some help with this. Thanks in advance!